# Is there any tool in linux that can monitor two folders in real time?

Tags: files

Is there any tool in linux that can monitor two folders and have the contents of folder a synced to folder b in real time?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd?

Comment: Depending on how i should interpret your question i would go for https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo or a bind mount

Comment: On the same filesystem or between two different ones / a local and remote one? If it's on the same filesystem, why not just use a symlink?

Comment: Do you have specific requirements for "real time", or you just mean "continuously"?